# How to pass a variable from PlayFramework 1.2.4 to Javascript

Tags: javascript, playframework-1.x

I've found this nice tutorial on GMAP V3 working with json http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/ the javascript is fine and it's working for me.

Now, I want to have the JSON from the controller of Play ;

Here is the controller :

```
public static void handleSubmit2(Bill bill)
    {

Gson gson; 


        Location l = new Location((long) 1,"u222","fes","morococ","37.401220","-12.125604","8 25 98");
        Location l2 = new Location((long) 1,"u222","fes","morococ","34.401220","-122.125604","8 25 98");
        Location l3 = new Location((long) 1,"u222","fes","morococ","40.401220","-50.125604","8 25 98");

        List<Location> locs = new ArrayList<Location>();;
        locs.add(l);
        locs.add(l2);
        locs.add(l3);

        List<JsonValid> jsons = new ArrayList<JsonValid>();
        JsonValid jsonV = new JsonValid();

        for(int i = 0 ; i<locs.size();i++)
        {
            jsonV.title = locs.get(i).city;
            jsonV.lat = locs.get(i).latitude;
            jsonV.lng = locs.get(i).longitude;

            jsons.add(i, jsonV);

        }

        gson = new Gson();
        String jlocations = gson.toJson(jsons);

        //The format is valid when I see the output
        System.out.println("json = " + jlocations);

        render("@handleSubmit2",jlocations);
    }
```

Here is the view handleSubmit2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

        window.onload = function() {

            // Creating a new map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.9, 14.6),
              zoom: 6,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });


            // Creating the JSON data
            var json = ${jlocations};

            // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            // Looping through the JSON data
            for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
                var data = json[i],
                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.lat), parseFloat(data.lng));

                // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });

                // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
                (function(marker, data) {

                    // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });


                })(marker, data);

            }

        }

    })();
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Map for bill</h1>
    <div id="map" style="width:800px; height:500px"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

What shoud I put in my javascript so that it could get the JSON ?

Any suggestions, any links that could help please.

P.S : I'm so terrible at Javascript and a beginner with Play so please be tolerant.

Best regards and Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What the controller is doing there is passing the variable jlocations to the "template processing" stage with the @handleSubmit2 name for the templating engine to process it, so depending what template engine are you using and how are you rendering it, and then we can help you on how to access it from javascript. So you need to update the post with the view code

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've updated the post with the view of handleSubmit2.html

Comment: see [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/controllers) and [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/templates) you need to call renderArgs.put('jlocations', jlocations) before the render()

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added renderArgs but It's always not displaying the map.

Comment: go step-by-step, first you can start with a simple console.log("data: " + json); after the json var is assigned on your view and see the output in the console

Comment: I've put it, in my play console, nothing is displayed

Comment: I think it's not going to be displayed in play console , it has to do something with the browser ? I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with javascript

Comment: yes I'm referring the browser's console, look on the browser in which you're testing, you need to open the developer tools and see the console (in firefox is CTRL+SHIFT+I or Tools/Web Developer/Toggle Tools)

Comment: Oops, I forgot that it's on firebug I'll see what it is displaying

Comment: It says that property id is invalid with the json :: SyntaxError: invalid property id
 

var json = [{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;fes&quot;,&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;40.4

Comment: in the view code you need to assign var json = ${jlocations.raw()} please read the link about templates above

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and being patient with me. It worked !! I'm able to see the map and also the markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So resuming:

1)  in order to pass the parameter to the view: call renderArgs.put("jlocations", jlocations) before the render()

2)  in order to render the json quotes correctly: in the view code you need to assign var json = ${jlocations.raw()}

as a tip: use the browser's console

Comment: Thank you again ! for the renderArgs please edit : we use double quotes not simple ones